# How to make my motion path update automatically?

Tags: animation

Whether I'm using an object or a bone, I'd like my motion path to update automatically. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This finally works with the latest Blender versions (I tested with 3.0).
If you turn on the rec button in the timeline and move your animated object, the motion path (generated initially from the Object properties tab) will update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The Motion Paths still don't get automatically updated, in realtime, if we change the Interpolation Type [ T ] in the Dope Sheet Editor for Selected Key Frame(s).

The best solution I found was to Add to Quick Favorites the **Update Path Button** and **Update All Paths Button** (which are located, as presented by @OMVT, in the Properties Editor » Object Properties Tab » Motion Paths Panel)a, so that I can easily recall these Operators in the 3D Viewport Editor or in the Properties Editor —when mouse cursor is hovering these Areas; although doesn't work in Timeline/Dope Sheet Editor/Graph Editor unfortunately, but this is just a small inconvenience compared to the advantage of using Quick Favorites feature (I personally use [ Q ] for recalling that).

Alternatively, a more rough way to Update these Motion Paths is just to redo them from Selected Key Frame(s) of Bone(s)/Object(s), is to use the Pose Menu » Motion Paths » Calculate Operator (or Clear Operator then Calculate Operator).
To make things easy, I also have [ Ctrl+T ] for Calculate and [ Alt+T ] for Clear, as Assigned Shortcuts —which is nice for general purposes.
This alternative method is what I used to do before learning about the Update functionalities from the Properties Editor.

Happy Blending.